# Adding a variable into Jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm trying to graph and chart and everything works great if I enter in numbers manually. Such as

```
chart = $.jqplot('chartContainer', 
        [[[0, firstActual],[.5, trajectory]],
        [[0, firstGoal],[1, secondGoal],[2, thirdGoal],[3, fourthGoal],[4, fifthGoal]],
        [[.5, trajectory]]], {
```

The variables were defined beforehand and work fine. Now if I wanted to do something like this

```
var test = "["+0+"," +firstActual+"], ["+.5+", "+trajectory+"]";

chart = $.jqplot('chartContainer', 
        [[test],
        [[0, firstGoal],[1, secondGoal],[2, thirdGoal],[3, fourthGoal],[4, fifthGoal]],
        [[.5, trajectory]]], {
```

The first line will not print. I'm guessing this has something to do with test being a String? Is there anyway to make test appear inside the jqplot function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the array to test variable as an array, not as string.

```
var test = [[0, firstActual], [.5, trajectory]]

chart = $.jqplot('chartContainer', 
    [test,
    [[0, firstGoal],[1, secondGoal],[2, thirdGoal],[3, fourthGoal],[4, fifthGoal]],
    [[.5, trajectory]]], {
```

If you for some reason need to form test as a string, you could use `JSON.parse()` to parse the string to array

```
var test = JSON.parse('[[' + 0 + ', "' + firstActual + '"], [' + .5 + ', "' + trajectory + '"]]');
```